# Please merge or remove bio-fuels tag

Tags: support, tag-blacklisting

My apologies, I created a bio-fuels tag for [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2074/is-demand-for-biofuels-causing-degredation-of-the-environment-in-third-world-coun).

After creating the question I created the correct tag biofuels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any unused tag will automatically be removed after a while.

Comment: OK, just wasn't sure if the old one shouldn't be removed as they are quite similar and someone might pick up the wrong one.

Comment: @xiao We can't easily remove a tag completely, we have to wait for the daily process that deletes unused tags.